# How to (horizontally) align text of PDTextField in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, textbox, pdfbox, text-alignment

I have a program that create TextFields inside a PDF-file so it can be used as a form. I would like to have the text I write in the TextFields I created to be centered  though. How is that possible? My code currently looks like this:

```
PDTextField textBox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
textBox.setPartialName("Field " + j + " " + i);
defaultAppearanceString = "/Helv 8 Tf 0 g"; //Textsize: 8
textBox.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);
acroForm.getFields().add(textBox);

PDAnnotationWidget widget = textBox.getWidgets().get(0);
PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(inputField.getX(), inputField.getY(), inputField.getWidth(), inputField.getHeight());
widget.setRectangle(rect);
widget.setPage(page);
widget.setPrinted(true);
page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
```

and I thought of an easy function to align text like this:

```
textBox.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);
```

but I didn't find it.

[image: My problem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Q flag:

```
textBox.setQ(PDTextField.QUADDING_CENTERED);
```

Other possible values are QUADDING_RIGHT and QUADDING_LEFT (which is the default).

Comment: Thanks, I had to use `textBox.setQ(1);` though, because `PDVariableText.QUADDING_CENTERED` is not visible.

Comment: Could it be you're not using the latest version? This was fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3925 .

Comment: Ah yes, I was still using 2.0.7 instead of 2.0.8