# Apache PDFBox: Get alignment and font from a PDAnnotationWidget or PDTextField

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have an existing pdf file with form fields, which can be filled by a user. This form fields have a font and text alignment which were defined when creating the pdf file.

I use Apache PDFBox to find the form field in the pdf:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
PDAcroForm form = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

PDTextField textField = (PDTextField)form.getField("anyFieldName");
if (textField == null) {
  textField = (PDTextField)form.getField("fieldsContainer.anyFieldName");
}

List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = textField.getWidgets();
PDAnnotationWidget annotation = null;
if (widgets != null && !widgets.isEmpty()) {
  annotation = widgets.get(0);

  /* font and alignment needed here */
}
```

If I set the content of the form field with

```
textField.setValue("This is the text");
```

then the text in the form field has the same font and alignment as predefined for this field.

But I need the alignment and the font for a second field (which is not a form field btw.).

How to find out which alignment (left, center, right) and which font (I need a `PDType1Font` and its size in point) is defined for this form field? Sth. like `font = annotation.getFont()` and `alignment = annotation.getAlignment()` which both do not exist.

How to get font and alignment?

21. 12. 17: Edit

Where I need the font is this:

```
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, false);
content.setFont(font, size); /* Here I need font and size from the text field above */
content.beginText();
content.showText("My very nice text");
content.endText();
```

I need the font for the `setFont()` call.

Comment: re alignment, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767319/how-to-horizontally-align-text-of-pdtextfield-in-pdfbox or call getQ()..

Comment: re font, the simplest would be to call `getDefaultAppearance()` and call the setter for your new field.

Comment: `getQ()` works, thanks. The alignment part of my question is solved now. But for the font I still need a solution. Copying the appearences is not a possibility here because I would override other properties of my destination field.

Comment: I didn't suggest to copy the appearances, only the default appearance of the field. For example, if it is "/Helv 0 Tf 0 g", then the font part is "/Helv 0 Tf" ("0 g" is the color). The font either already exists in the /AcroForm/DR part (acroform default resources), or you'd have to add it to the resources of the appearance **stream** of your field (more tricky - ask if needed, attach PDF if possible).

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know how to set the font. I use a `PDPageContentStream`. In my question I added an example where I want to use the font.

Comment: I missed the part `which is not a form field btw.`. Now I understand why you need a PDFont object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the PDFont, do this:

```
String defaultAppearance = textField.getDefaultAppearance(); // usually like "/Helv 12 Tf 0 0 1 rg"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\/(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)\\s.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(defaultAppearance);
if (!m.find() || m.groupCount() < 2)
{
    // oh-oh
}
String fontName = m.group(1);
int fontSize = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
PDAnnotationWidget widget = textField.getWidgets().get(0);
PDResources res = widget.getAppearance().getNormalAppearance().getAppearanceStream().getResources();
PDFont fieldFont = res.getFont(COSName.getPDFName(fontName));
if (fieldFont == null)
{
    fieldFont = acroForm.getDefaultResources().getFont(COSName.getPDFName(fontName));
}
System.out.println(fieldFont + "; " + fontSize);
```

This retrieves the font object from the resource dictionary of the resource dictionary of the first widget of your field. If the font isn't there, the default resource dictionary is checked. Note that there are no null checks, you need to add them. At the botton of the code you'll get a PDFont object and a number.

Re alignment, call `getQ()`, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767319/how-to-horizontally-align-text-of-pdtextfield-in-pdfbox).

Comment: That does the job. Thank you very much.