# acroform text field not align to right

Tags: pdfbox

I have [this acro form](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1jFbsYGFOnx8EMiHgDsE8LQtfwJHSa5Gh&export=download)

I am trying this code to align field to right :

```
acroForm.getField("NewRentWithoutChargesChf").setValue("1.00");
((PDTextField) acroForm.getField("NewRentWithoutChargesChf")).setQ(PDVariableText.QUADDING_RIGHT); //align right not works
```

I expect field to be right aligned but it doesn't (still left).

Already checked this realted SO [How to (horizontally) align text of PDTextField in PDFBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767319/how-to-horizontally-align-text-of-pdtextfield-in-pdfbox)

Comment: Consider *first* setting the quadding value and *thereafter* changing the field value. PDFBox (and many other PDF libraries, too) generates appearances (if at all) only when the field value is set, not when some other field properties may be changed. (I don't know whether PDFBox supports the quadding value but even if it does, it requires the appropriate order of instructions.)

Comment: @mkl seems weird to me, but you are right ! it works! thank you a lot

Comment: I just tested it, too; PDFBox does support quadding. I'll make my comment an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFBox (and many other PDF libraries, too) generates appearances (if at all) only when the *field value* is set; they don't update the appearance again and again each time some other *field property* changes.

Thus, you should *first* set the **quadding value** and only *thereafter* change the **field value**, i.e.

```java
((PDTextField) acroForm.getField("NewRentWithoutChargesChf")).setQ(PDVariableText.QUADDING_RIGHT); //align right works
acroForm.getField("NewRentWithoutChargesChf").setValue("1.00");
```