# How to (vertically) align text of PDTextField in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, textbox, pdfbox, text-alignment

I have writen a form with LibreOffice that includes some named fields to fill out via PdfBox. The fields are properly set up with text-alignment (all left-centered) but PdfBox simply ignores the vertical aligment. Both on text fields and on labels. The fields get aligned bottom and the labels top. Besides the optical difference in presentation, the values of the fields also get cut on lower letters like "g" etc.

I would provide a image but i don`t have enough reputation...

Provided that I cannot be the only one with this problem, I`ve found this answer here on SO [How to (horizontally) align text of PDTextField in PDFBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767319/how-to-horizontally-align-text-of-pdtextfield-in-pdfbox).
There is a function mentioned that provides this function for horizontal alignment

```
textBox.setQ(PDTextField.QUADDING_CENTERED);
```

I`ve tested this and it works.

The overall call in my programm is rather simple:

```
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = _pdf.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
PDTextField field = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField(name);
if (field != null)
{
    field.setQ(PDTextField.QUADDING_LEFT);
    field.setValue(value);
}
else
{
    LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, "No field found with name:" + name);
}
```

Unfortunately (or out of sheer stupidity on my end; I blame the temperatures) I didn`t find any way to force PdfBox to any aligment on the vertical axis.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

As per request here is an example (not the real version because it is a document from work - nonetheless it is the same construction as the original):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JKyuFqkb9B8Q9M61uxncAJXzMOo7zvJ5/view?usp=sharing

The field is named `err_desc`.
Also I provides in the pdf doc a picture of the result in the original filled form.

I've also tried to simply make the vertical space of the text field bigger. That unfortunately didn't work as the text seems to stick to the bottom and simply left more space above the text.

Comment: I think it's not possible. Unless you write your own software to fill the appearance stream (thus it would change again if you reedit with Adobe Reader later). To see what I mean, get the source code and look for `AppearanceGeneratorHelper.insertGeneratedAppearance()`, and there for `initialOffset`, and then look how `y` is calculated.

Comment: We could have a look at your PDF if you upload it to a sharehoster. Please do this and mention the field name, and the PDFBox version that you are using (hopefully 2.0.15).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Hi, sorry for this delay i was on vacation over the weekend. I've edited your request and i hope it works. I will look up your first suggestion and try it out. Thanks

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Oh, and yes my PdfBox Version is 2.0.15.

Comment: As @Tilman already indicated, PDFBox does not *simply ignore the vertical aligment* because the PDF does not *contain* any alignment information PDFBox could ignore. Thus, PDFBox decides to use the observed alignment all by itself. As a consequence, therefore, the choice PDFBox makes should be improved...

Comment: I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4568  for now.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you. I've also looked throu your mention of the PdfBox code and I think the problem is that the baseline of the font gets calculated wrong and therefore the allignment gets misplaced, Why it gets calculated wrong is beyond my understandig or rather my free time slot at the moment.